# set view width to blank size

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I have 3 child views in a container view. I would like to fill one child view's width to blank size according to device width.

```
<View width="Ti.UI.FILL" height="Ti.UI.SIZE" layout="horizontal">
     <!-- 1 --><View width="60" height="Ti.UI.SIZE" backgroundColor="yellow" />
     <!-- 2 --><View width="Ti.UI.FILL" height="Ti.UI.SIZE"  backgroundColor="red" />
     <!-- 3 --><View width="80" height="Ti.UI.SIZE"  backgroundColor="orange" />
</View>
```

[image: Preview]

This code is not working correctly. View is in third place is not showing near the second. is there any method for filling one view not giving actual width size?

Answer (score 0):

I get help from ti.slack. Below approach is working. May be this helps anybody.

```
<View width="Ti.UI.FILL" height="Ti.UI.SIZE">
     <!-- 1 --><View width="60" height="Ti.UI.SIZE" backgroundColor="yellow" left="0" />
     <!-- 2 --><View width="Ti.UI.FILL" height="Ti.UI.SIZE"  backgroundColor="red" left="60" right="80" />
     <!-- 3 --><View width="80" height="Ti.UI.SIZE"  backgroundColor="orange" />
</View>
```